# Expand list in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In `bash` I wrote
    `echo prefix{t1,t2,t3}suffix`
and got
    `prefixt1suffix prefixt2suffix prefixt3suffix`

Is something like this present in PowerShell?
List expantion I mean.

Comment: Is using a loop an option?

Comment: `"t1","t2","t3" | % { "prefix" + $_ }`

Comment: Maybe you can use 'splatting' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448911/how-to-expand-a-powershell-array-when-passing-it-to-a-function

Comment: @arco444: no, loop is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic expansion, but you can do it easily with `ForEach-Object` cmdlet or array's `ForEach` method in [PS 4 and higher](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/):

```powershell
't1', 't2', 't3' | ForEach-Object {'prefix' + $_ + 'suffix'}

@('t1', 't2', 't3').ForEach({'prefix' + $_ + 'suffix'})
```

Comment: It is not a solution, but nice enough. Thanks.

Comment: @OlegG I'm curious, do you have any specific reasons, that require the list expansion to be absolutely the same as in bash? Because I believe that internally bash loops through the collection too, there is no other way to do it. PowerShell just doesn't have this particular shortcut, that's all.

Comment: Just compare Bash command line `vim -d /some/directory/file{1,2}.ps1` with that I have write in PowerShell and you'll see my reason.

Comment: @OlegG I see. It's true, despite its name PowerShell is really lacking in the "shell" aspect. Perhaps you could try [PSReadline module](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) - it really tries to bring a *nix shell expirience to the PS (no list expansion, though).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other ways are:

```
't1', 't2', 't3' | % {"prefix$($_)suffix"}
```

and

```
't1', 't2', 't3' | % {'prefix{0}suffix' -f $_}
```

Comment: It is not a solution, but also nice. Thanks.